Prove that $19^{1976}$ + $76^{1976}$ is: 1) Divisible by the $4^{th}$ Fermat prime. 2) Divisible by at least 4 distinct primes other than $F_4$
Prove that  $19^{1976}$ + $76^{1976}$ is: 1) Divisible by the $4^{th}$ Fermat prime. 2) Divisible by at least 4 distinct primes other than $F_4$
Here's a partial solution

We know that $76=19·4$. Thus the expression becomes,
$$19^{1976}+76^{1976}=19^{1976}·(1+4^{1976})=19^{1976}·(1+(2^{16})^{247})=\cdots $$ $$\cdots =19^{1976}·(2^{16}+1)·((2^{16})^{246}-(2^{16})^{245}+···+1)$$
since $2^{16}=2^{{2}^{4}}$. Hence $F_4$ divides the given expression
For the sake of contradiction, suppose it has at most 3 distinct primes beside $F_4$. We then have $P_1·P_2·P_3·F_4\mid19^{1976}+76^{19776}$.  From observation we found that $P_1=19$(WLOG) implying that $P_2·P_3\mid((2^{16})^{246}-(2^{16})^{245}+···+1$
. From here I stuck figuring out which kind of operation or argument I would use to show that $P_2$ and $P_3$ are not enough (That ${P_2}^{a}·{P_3}^{b}$ is not its prime factorization for positive integers $a$ and $b$)


You should fix the title.

Welcome to Math SE. Note that $247=13\times 19$.

One of its factor is 1113051771018017

$1976=8\times247$. $a^{247}+b^{247}$ is divisible by $a+b$.

@Guruprasad how did you get that result please?

@John Omielan
Alright  thanks for the tip

@Gerry Myerson
Thanks so much man. i forgot abouut that it came so handy

@BrayantTagne See Gerry Myerson's comment

If you're able to solve the problem now, Bryant, you can write up a solution and post it as an answer (although the software may make you wait for a while before you're allowed to popst an answer to your own question).

@Gerry Myerson
Can i just edit the post?

Yes, but there are advantages to posting an answer. Other users can upvote it, so you get points. You can accept your own answer, and get points for that. The system software will keep pushing unanswered questions onto the front page from time to time, which can be annoying if the question has actually been answered by editing an answer into the body of the question. But it's up to you.

@Gerry Myerson
Alright thanks man, i will do what you suggest

@GerryMyerson FYI, re: "You can accept your own answer, and get points for that", note that as explained in the answer to the Network Meta's FAQ How does accepting an answer work?, in the "Can I accept my own self-answer?" section, "Accepting your own answer won't award you any reputation". For example, I didn't receive any reputation on accepting this relatively recent self-answer. Also, earlier, one can post a self-answer at any time, e.g., when posting the question.

@John, thanks, news to me.
